# Why does Swift URL's init?(string: String, relativeTo: URL?) add only the protocol?

Tags: swift, url, rfc

When I do

```
let baseUrl = URL(string: "ftp://www.foobar.com/foo/bar/")
let finalUrl = URL(string: "//barfoo.com/bar/foo", relativeTo: baseUrl)
print(finalUrl?.absoluteString ?? "ooops")
```

it prints `ftp://barfoo.com/bar/foo`

Is this expected behaviour? Is this documented somewhere?

[EDIT]
I was just wondering, because I'd expect that all the stuff, including server and path would be taken from the base url, like here:

```
let baseUrl = URL(string: "ftp://www.foobar.com/foo/bar/")
let finalUrl = URL(string: "boo/far", relativeTo: baseUrl)
print(finalUrl?.absoluteString ?? "ooops")
```

which prints `ftp://www.foobar.com/foo/bar/boo/far`.

Why is the server and everything else from the base url being ignored in the first example? Is that due to the `//` at the beginning? And is this part of some RFC or something or documented somewhere else?

Comment: This looks correct. What were you expecting this to return? What do you mean by "replace only the protocol?" By "protocol" I assume you mean scheme, and that's the one thing that **isn't** replaced.

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier.
 
Yes I mean the scheme (which will be interpreted in a way that will end up in using a certain protocol).
And yes, it's a bit confusing ... With "replace" actually I mean "added". 

What I found confusing is, that the only thing taken from the  baseUrl `ftp://www.foobar.com/foo/bar` is the `ftp:`, while "relativeTo" suggests that the full server and path will be used from the baseUrl.

I will clarify that with an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note, this is due to the `//` at the beginning. From the [URI RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3), the format of a URI is:

```
  URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
  hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
              / path-absolute
              / path-rootless
              / path-empty
```

When you begin your URI with `//`, you're indicating that it should replace the authority and path, which it does. As described in [Section 3.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3), a `path-absolute` cannot begin with `//`:

```
                / path-absolute   ; begins with "/" but not "//"
```

If your intention is to replace the path without modifying the authority (userinfo, host, port), then you can pass an absolute path (beginning with `/`) rather than an authority and path (beginning with `//`):

```
let finalUrl = URL(string: "/barfoo.com/bar/foo", relativeTo: baseUrl)
// ftp://www.foobar.com/barfoo.com/bar/foo
```

And if you want to append a path, you can pass a rootless path (not beginning with a `/`):

```
let finalUrl = URL(string: "barfoo.com/bar/foo", relativeTo: baseUrl)
// ftp://www.foobar.com/foo/barfoo.com/bar/foo
```

For operations more complex that this, you should definitely look at [URLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents) instead, which allows you to query and modify parts more explicitly and safely.

Comment: Thanks very much.  As I found out he  URI RFC, the. Section 5.2.2 describes an algorithm (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-5.2.2), to construct a target URI from  base uri and reference uri, which exactly matches, what we see here, in your and my examples.